# foreach function on $GLOBALS generates a fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

This function works on one field at a time:

```
foreach ($GLOBALS as $key => $value) {
if ($key === "special1") {
{$value = preg_replace('/src/','data-machin', $value);          
}}}
```

This one - with no condition (so it tries to proccess 360 fields) does not:

```
foreach ($GLOBALS as $key => $value) 
{$value = preg_replace('/src/','data-machin', $value);          
}
```

and generates this Fatal error: Cannot increment/decrement overloaded objects nor string offsets in /home/xxx/public_html/lib/mysqldb.php on line 145.

How could I make it work?

(Big picture: I am trying to implement a script to delay the loading of photos).

Comment: You already have the solution to your own problem.  `preg_replace()` doesn't take an array for its third parameter whether you like it or not.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, so now I know why it does not work, but I still need a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_replace` only makes sense for string values.

Thus, you may use the [`is_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php) function to check values when iterating:

```
foreach ($GLOBALS as $key => $value) {
    if (is_string($value)) {
        $value = preg_replace('/src/','data-machin', $value); 
    }
}
```

Also please note that this piece of code produces no side effects — i.e. the `$GLOBALS` array is **not** modified. You may consider using [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) instead:

```
foreach ($GLOBALS as $key => &$value) {
    ...
}
unset($value);
```

Comment: Yes! This woks with => &$value. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that using references inside a foreach yields many possible undesirable side-effects.

Comment: @JuliePelletier, yep good hint, added an `unset` after the loop which is a common practice.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is generally a bad idea to use globals and even worse to do such blind variable operations, you could do it that way:

```
foreach ($GLOBALS as $key => $value) {
    if (is_string($value)) {
        $GLOBALS[$key] = preg_replace('/src/','data-machin', $value);
    }
}
```

Updated to include `is_string()` which checks if the value is a string.

Comment: Yes same error, but it works with the condition provided by Alex:  if (is_string($value)) {... Alex, could you explain to me, what the condition does exactly? I am not a programmer, but I try to lean.

Comment: `is_string()` will check if the content is a string so that it is compatible with your `preg_replace()` call.

Comment: ok, thanks to you both. So here is my final working solution:

Comment: foreach ($GLOBALS as $key => &$value) {
    if (is_string($value)) {
 $GLOBALS[$key] = preg_replace('/src/','data-machin', $value);    }
}